# PyCharm 3.4 split tool windows in one column

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

How is possible to split tool windows in one column?

I can just Move to -> Top, Left but they substitute each other.  I would like something like this picture:

[image: pycharm split window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two windows for each side of the screen open at once.  So only a two-way split.  Drag the tab for the first window to one side of the bar, and the second tab to the other side of the bar, then click both tabs.  This example shows a split left panel between the project and structure tabs.

[image: split panel example]